# Get issue "Route [register] not defined."

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.8

I recently set up a local Laravel environment via Composer and call the project via VirtualHost, following my opinion:

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *: 80>
         ServerName inb.local
         ServerAdmin mail@private.com
         DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/laravel_test/public/"
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         <Directory "/var/www/html/laravel_test/public/">
             AllowOverride All
             Allow from All
         </ Directory>
         ErrorLog $ {APACHE_LOG_DIR} /error.log
         CustomLog $ {APACHE_LOG_DIR} /access.log combined
</ VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 inb.local
```

I can also call this page via inb.local and see the homepage with the Laravel headline and the URLs to the pages. For fun, I wanted to install a routing, but unfortunately does not work. My code looks like this:

**welcome.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <style>
            html, body {
                background-color: #fff;
                color: #636b6f;
                font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 200;
                height: 100vh;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .full-height {
                height: 100vh;
            }

            .flex-center {
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            .position-ref {
                position: relative;
            }

            .top-right {
                position: absolute;
                right: 10px;
                top: 18px;
            }

            .content {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .title {
                font-size: 84px;
            }

            .links > a {
                color: #636b6f;
                padding: 0 25px;
                font-size: 13px;
                font-weight: 600;
                letter-spacing: .1rem;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            .m-b-md {
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            @if (Route::has('login'))
                <div class="top-right links">
                    @auth
                        <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>

                        @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
                        @endif
                    @endauth
                </div>
            @endif

            <div class="content">
                <div class="title m-b-md">
                    Laravel
                </div>

                <div class="links">
                    <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
                    <a href="https://laravel.com/docs">Docs</a>
                    <a href="https://laracasts.com">Laracasts</a>
                    <a href="https://laravel-news.com">News</a>
                    <a href="https://blog.laravel.com">Blog</a>
                    <a href="https://nova.laravel.com">Nova</a>
                    <a href="https://forge.laravel.com">Forge</a>
                    <a href="https://github.com/laravel/laravel">GitHub</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**routes/web.php**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/register', ['name' => 'User']);
```

**register.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <style>
            html, body {
                background-color: #fff;
                color: #636b6f;
                font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 200;
                height: 100vh;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .full-height {
                height: 100vh;
            }

            .flex-center {
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            .position-ref {
                position: relative;
            }

            .top-right {
                position: absolute;
                right: 10px;
                top: 18px;
            }

            .content {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .title {
                font-size: 84px;
            }

            .links > a {
                color: #636b6f;
                padding: 0 25px;
                font-size: 13px;
                font-weight: 600;
                letter-spacing: .1rem;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            .m-b-md {
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            @if (Route::has('login'))
                <div class="top-right links">
                    @auth
                        <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>

                        @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
                        @endif
                    @endauth
                </div>
            @endif

            <div class="content">
                <div class="title m-b-md">
                    Hallo {{ $name }}!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I update the start page now, I get the error

```
 ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Route [register] not defined. (View: /var/www/html/laravel_test/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)
Previous exceptions

    Route [register] not defined. (0)
```

Am I missing a shot or what did I miss?

Answer (score 3):

`Route()` helper only works with named routes. For example a named route is like

```
Route::get('/hello, 'HelloController@hello)->name('hey');
```

then you can use it like `route('hey')`

So, in your case

```
Route::get('/register', 'SomeController@method')->name('register');
```

For more info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes

Comment: Okay I changed it to `Route::get('/register', SomeController@method)->name('register');` and created a `RegisterController` with method `method` and get the error `syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting ',' or ')'`. RegisterController extends from Class Controller

Comment: @Premox thats beause of missing `''` quotes, my bad let me update my answer

Comment: Sry for those stupid question. Dunno why but Laravel seems to be a lil' bit difficult. Wants to leearn to develope with it.

Comment: @Premox just keep practicing, once you understand the flow, it get easier. look for video tutorials, i'll suggest Academind

Comment: Another question: 
If I click on my link I get the issue `Not Found

The requested URL /register was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at inb.local Port 80`.` 
The URL is set to `register` in `web.php` and it should direct to the index-Method in `RegisterController`.

Comment: will need more information regarding how the project was setup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194244/discussion-between-premox-and-aditya-thakur).